# MYSQL Database to Highcharts graph via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a database with timestamp for three different parameters but for educational purposes only I am trying to do just one graph on one parameter in real time.
Here is my php code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $count =0;
    echo '[';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '['.$row["time"].','.$row["temperature"].']';
    $count++;
        if ($count<"100") {
        echo ',';
        }
    }
    echo ']';
} 
else {
    echo "[[],[]]";
}


$link->close();
```

`?>`

The following php code displays:

```
[[1511533905000,34],[1511534125000,34],[1511534201000,34],[1511535161000,34],[1511535221000,34],[1511535281000,34],[1511535306000,34],[1511535606000,34],[1511535907000,34],[1511536207000,34],[1511536507000,34],[1511536807000,34],[1511537108000,34],[1511537408000,34],[1511537708000,34],[1511538070000,85],[1511538370000,31],[1511538670000,31],[1511538971000,30],[1511539271000,30],[1511539571000,30],[1511539872000,30],[1511540172000,30],[1511540472000,30],[1511540773000,30],[1511936414000,25],[1511936714000,24],[1511937014000,85],[1511937315000,24],[1511937616000,24],[1511937916000,24],[1511938216000,24],[1511938517000,24],[1511938817000,24],[1511939117000,24],[1511939417000,24],[1511939718000,24],[1511940018000,24],[1511950908000,85],[1511951208000,23],[1511951509000,23],[1511951809000,23],[1511952109000,23],[1511952410000,23],[1511952710000,22],[1511953010000,22],[1511953310000,22],[1511953611000,22],[1511953911000,22],[1511954211000,22],[1511954512000,22],[1511954812000,22],[1511955112000,22],[1511955412000,22],[1511955713000,22],[1512056186000,31],[1512056486000,85],[1512056787000,30],[1512057087000,31],[1512057387000,30],[1512057688000,30],[1512057988000,30],[1512058289000,30],[1512058589000,30],[1512058889000,30],[1512059189000,30],]
```

now here is the html code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
        useUTC: false
        }   
});
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            //defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        events:{
            load: refreshChart()
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
        },
        tooltip: {             
            valueSuffix: ' C'
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'linear',
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature ( C)'
      },
    },
        series: [{}]
    });

$.getJSON("index.php", function(json) {    /*Get the array data in data.php using jquery getJSON function*/
    options.series[0].data = json;        /*assign the array variable to chart data object*/
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); /*create a new chart*/
});

function refreshChart(){                 /*function is called every set interval to refresh(recreate the chart) with the new data from data.php*/
    setInterval(function(){
        $.getJSON("index.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    },6000);
}
```

});

But the graph doesnt display anything? Anyhelp pls?

Comment: Your generating invalid json, notice the last `,`, (this will break your javascript) view your browser console. Avoid compiling your own json and use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead.

Comment: try: `$output = array(); $i=0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $output[] = array(
   $row["time"],
   $row["temperature"]
  );
 }
}
echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: resolved it while using your code, Kevin. from [[1511533905000,34],[1511534125000,34] now it displays [["1511533905000","34"],["1511534125000","34"] but still it doesnt display anything.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!! I just converted the output of my array in the index.php.

```
$output[] = array(((float)($row["time"])),((int)($row["temperature"])));
```

in this way both the timestamp and the value of the temperature are both valid json.